# Flask-SQLAlchemy with multiple gunicorn workers causes inconsistent reads

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, gunicorn

I have developed a Flask application, and so far I have only ever deployed it using a single worker. The app connects to an SQLite DB using Flask-SQLAlchemy. In the beginning, I check if my DB already has data, and if not, I initialize some data like a default setup user like this:

```
    root_user = User.query.filter_by(username='root').one_or_none()
    if not root_user:
        new_user = User(username="root", password_hash="SomeLongAndSecurePasswordHash")
        new_user.roles = [serveradmin_role]

        db.session.add(new_user)
```

When I run this code with multiple gunicorn workers and threads, the workers crash because they try to create multiple root users, which fails my UNIQUE constraint in the DB. Apparently, they all read the DB at the same time, when the root user does not exists yet, and then they all try to write the user to the DB, which only works for one of the workers.

What would be a good way of preventing this? I feel like my code should just deal better with the SQLAlchemy error being thrown, or is there anything I am missing here? The same thing might also happen in production, if two people try to create the same user at exactly the same time, how would I deal with it there?

Comment: I got the same problem, and I tried `User.query.with_for_update()`, still not working at the 'exactly the same time' condition.